# How do I use the built in password reset/change views with my own templates

Tags: python, django, passwords

For example I can point the `url '^/accounts/password/reset/$'` to `django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset` with my template filename in the context but I think need to send more context details.

I need to  know exactly what context to add for each of the password reset and change views.

Comment: Given the title of this question I don't think `context` is the right thing you're looking for!

Comment: Just to confirm, by "context" I meant the dictionary of extra data that is the 3rd argument to a url line. aka extra data or [kwargs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.conf.urls.defaults.url). Sorry for confusion, please edit the question, anyone who can.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

If you take a look at the sources for [django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py) you'll see that it uses [`RequestContext`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/__init__.py). The upshot is, you can use Context Processors to modify the context which may allow you to inject the information that you need.

The b-list has a good [introduction to context processors](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/).

Edit (I seem to have been confused about what the actual question was):

You'll notice that `password_reset` takes a named parameter called `template_name`:

```
def password_reset(request, is_admin_site=False, 
            template_name='registration/password_reset_form.html',
            email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
            password_reset_form=PasswordResetForm, 
            token_generator=default_token_generator,
            post_reset_redirect=None):
```

Check [password_reset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) for more information.

... thus, with a urls.py like:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^/accounts/password/reset/$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'my_templates/password_reset.html'}),
     ...
)
```

`django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset` will be called for URLs matching `'/accounts/password/reset'` with the keyword argument `template_name = 'my_templates/password_reset.html'`.

Otherwise, you don't need to provide any context as the `password_reset` view takes care of itself. If you want to see what context you have available, you can trigger a `TemplateSyntax` error and look through the stack trace find the frame with a local variable named `context`. If you want to modify the context then what I said above about context processors is probably the way to go.

In summary: what do you need to do to use your own template? Provide a `template_name` keyword argument to the view when it is called. You can supply keyword arguments to views by including a dictionary as the third member of a URL pattern tuple.

Comment: I believe the question is about using different templates with builtin views - Context processors doesn't factor into it!

Comment: any idea, how to let `registration/password_reset_email.html` actually contain html elements like: `<div>`, `<a>` because this sends text only

Comment: @mabdrabo - check out [this article](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html) on how to get HTML working.

Answer (score 27):

Strongly recommend this article.

I just plugged it in and it worked

http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/django-resetting-passwords-with.html

Comment: great link, thanks. for those following the link - django-registration now includes the default auth views...so all you have to do is create the templates detailed in the above link. also - use django-crispy-forms if you want to avoid all the manual html form work he did as well.

Comment: There's some legacy Django code I have to manage at work, but I barely know anything about the framework. That guy saved my ass! Great tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the link! I think this should be the accepted answer since like you said, plugged it in and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

You just need to wrap the existing functions and pass in the template you want. For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset

def my_password_reset(request, template_name='path/to/my/template'):
    return password_reset(request, template_name)
```

To see this just have a look at the function declartion of the built in views:

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L74

Comment: Not the simplest way to do that. You can pass in a dictionary as a third part of a URL patterns tuple or, if you feel you really must wrap the function, you could use: password_reset = functools.partial(password, template_name = "path/to/my/template")

Answer (score 8):

You can do the following:

1. add to your urlpatterns (r'^/accounts/password/reset/$', password_reset)
2. put your template in '/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html'
3. make your app come before 'django.contrib.auth' in INSTALLED_APPS

Explanation:

When the templates are loaded, they are searched in your INSTALLED_APPS variable in settings.py .
The order is dictated by the definition's rank in INSTALLED_APPS, so since your app come before 'django.contrib.auth' your template were loaded (reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader).

Motivation of approach:

1. I want be more dry and don't repeat for any view(defined by django) the template name (they are already defined in django)
2. I want a smallest url.py

Answer (score 2):

Another, perhaps simpler, solution is to add your override template directory to the DIRS entry of the TEMPLATES setting in settings.py.  (I think this setting is new in Django 1.8.  It may have been called TEMPLATE_DIRS in previous Django versions.)

Like so:

```
TEMPLATES = [
   {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # allow overriding templates from other installed apps                                                                                                
        'DIRS': ['my_app/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
}]
```

Then put your override template files under `my_app/templates`.  So the overridden password reset template would be `my_app/templates/registration/password_reset_form.html`

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.django.contrib.auth.views.password_change) says that there only one context variable, `form`.

If you're having trouble with login (which is common), the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) says there are three context variables:

- `form`: A Form object representing the login form. See the forms documentation for more on Form objects.
- `next`: The URL to redirect to after successful login. This may contain a query string, too.
- `site_name`: The name of the current Site, according to the SITE_ID setting.

Comment: The documentation says there is an "optional argument" called "template_name" which seems more relevant.

Comment: The optional argument is an argument to the function, not context provided to the form.

Comment: Mmm- I think the question is confusing in that it talks about 'context' when really all that's relevant to solving this is the arguments of the `password_reset` view.

Answer (score 1):

I was using this two lines in the url and the template from the admin what i was changing to my need

```
url(r'^change-password/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change', {
    'template_name': 'password_change_form.html'}, name="password-change"),
url(r'^change-password-done/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done', {
    'template_name': 'password_change_done.html'
    }, name="password-change-done")
```