# Django Forgot Password function changing default email

Tags: python, django, email, passwords, reset

I created a Forgot Password functionality for my website using the password_reset function that is built in Django
it sends an email like so:

```
You're receiving this e-mail because you requested a password reset for your user account at example.com.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://example.com/reset/3/2zf-fe162b1d79f1b85c3630/

Your username, in case you've forgotten: Angie

Thanks for using our site!

The example.com team
```

Where would I change this email?

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388800/django-how-do-i-use-the-built-in-password-reset-change-views-with-my-own-templat

Comment: @MatToufoutu I followed an example [here](http://shrenikp.webs.com/apps/blog/entries/show/7133721-implement-forgot-password-on-customer-ui-) but for some reason I am getting an error Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: for line {% url 'views.cust_password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %} Would you know what i forgot to add?

Comment: @Angie: please don't treat this as a discussion forum. If you have a followup problem, post a followup question.

Comment: @Angie: that example you linked to in your comment provides just really unnecessary boiler plate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default template for that email is `django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html`. You can override it by providing your own template `templates/registration/password_reset_email.html` in your top app directory as usual.

Comment: I actually managed by myself after searching through 50 more links on the internet, but thank you for your help. I just wish there was more tutorials for beginners instead of people who already "mastered" django attempt to help a person who doesn't know much about django terminology, but that is just me ranting.

Comment: @Angie: patches, especially documentation patches, are always welcome.

Comment: why does it only send the content of the .html as text, meaning the email sent would read like `<div> hi <br/> here's your new pass: xxxx </div>`

Answer (score 0):

For those who get the error:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: for line {% url 'views.cust_password_reset_confirm' uidb36=uid token=token %}
```

when trying to send the reset password email, watch out the password_reset_confirm url. It should be something like:

```
(r'^password-reset-confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$','django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm', {'template_name':'accounts/password_reset_confirm.html', 'post_reset_redirect':'/accounts/logout/'}),
```