# Django password reset function

Tags: django, django-admin

I am a newbie and have read through Django docs. How can I perform the standard password reset function?

When a user clicks the "reset password" button, the application should ask for the old password, the new password and a confirmation of the new password. Once this is validated, Django should reset the password.

What is the simplest way to perform this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an app like [django-password-reset](https://github.com/brutasse/django-password-reset)

Or look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388800/django-how-do-i-use-the-built-in-password-reset-change-views-with-my-own-templa) SO post, or [this](http://drumcoder.co.uk/blog/2010/apr/09/django-reset-password/) blog

Comment: Good to see @Karthikr answer,more blog if anybody have please post it here for my reference.

Comment: why? This does not answer your question ?