# Crispy Forms and Django Password Reset Form

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

How can I use the crispy form helper to control the layout of the form elements, for the builtin forms, such as is mentioned in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388800/how-do-i-use-the-built-in-password-reset-change-views-with-my-own-templates) post?

Answer (score 2):

i think its late but i hope it helps you:

**forms.py**

```
class PasswordResetFormExtra(auth.forms.PasswordResetForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(PasswordResetFormExtra, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'        
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'email',
            Div(
               Submit('submit', 'Reset password', css_class='btn btn-default'),
               HTML('<a class="btn btn-default" href="/">Cancel</a>'),
               css_class='text-left',
            )
        )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset
from .forms import(
        PasswordResetFormExtra,
        )

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
         (r'^/accounts/password/reset/$', password_reset, {
         'template_name': 'my_templates/password_reset.html',
         'password_reset_form':PasswordResetFormExtra,
         }),

    )
```

**password_reset.html**

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```