# URL reset password, Django 1.6.5

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I use django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset to reset user password

```
 (r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm'),
```

I got this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /reset/Nw/3u5-5654a2cadfa432b86577/
Reverse for 'password_reset_complete' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

When I put argument name='password_reset_confirm' in the url:

```
(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
    'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

I get this error:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

(and Eclipse shows there is a an error: syntax error detectiong tuple)
Anyone has experience with it ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

For the first error:
The django app probably requires you to add password_reset_complete to your url configuration

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15203487/1714030

The second error:

You probably need to add the "url" function:
    (Trying to declare name=... in a tuple generates the error)

```
url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
name='password_reset_confirm')
```

Hope this helps