# How to implement forget password functionality using Django and Python

Tags: python, django

I need one help. I need to implement the forget password functionality using Django. I am using the Django signup and login page. My code is below:

login.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
 <h2>Log in</h2>
  {% if form.errors %}
    <p style="color: red">Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}<br>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <p><small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small></p>
        {% endif %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Log in</button>
    <a href="{% url 'signup' %}">New to My Site? Sign up</a>
  </form>
  {% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
class Signup(View):

    """ this class is used for user signup """

    def get(self, request):
        """ this function used to get the sign up form """
        form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'plant/signup.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        """ this function used for post the sign up data """
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login')


class AuthLogin(View):

    """ Its for login """

    def get(self, request):
        """ this function used to get the login form """
        form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'plant/login.html', {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        """ this function used for post the login data """
        form = AuthenticationForm(None, request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            login(request, form.get_user())
        return redirect('/')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="plant/index.html")),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout,
        {'next_page': 'login'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', core_views.AuthLogin.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^signup/$', core_views.Signup.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

In login page I should have the `forget password` link. When user will click on it, the reset password page will open and another one condition is after trying 3 wrong attempt the `forget password` button will be invisible for 1 hour.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use the built in password reset/change views with my own templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388800/how-do-i-use-the-built-in-password-reset-change-views-with-my-own-templates)

Answer (score 2):

Do not create this functionality yourself but use the built-in Django auth views. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views

The only thing you need to do is add the contrib auth urls to your project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

This gives you all views like login, logout, password reset etc.

If you want to customise the templates, copy the templates form `/path/to/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/` to your app `project/app/templates/registration/` and make any customisations 
there.

If your app is listed before `'django.contrib.auth'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` (it should *always* be like that) your custom templates will be picked first.