# Will the django built in password reset views work with a custom user that inherits from AbstractBaseUser?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I an going to build a custom django user and a custom log in and sign up views and I want to know if the I should build a custom password reset view as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user):

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model, but you want to add some additional profile information, you could subclass `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` and add your custom profile fields

What this means is that an `AbstractUser` will inherit all functions that can be applied to the `User` model, so I believe that, as long as you didn't remove password-related fields, the `ResetPasswordView` will work.

Another way to look at this is through authentication views. If your custom `AbstractUser` model can get by the default login/signup auth views (even changes through the admin dashboard), I don't see any problem why your model can't take `PasswordReserView`.

I've done this multiple times. Although I've never reset my user's password, I can guarantee the default views will work as long as you don't modify your `username`, `email`, and `password` fields (you can try, but that may ruin things)

Comment: What I am going to do in the custom user model is that I am going to reset the `USERNAME_FIELD` to be an email `EmailField()` and the username will be a normal `CharField()` I will call it full_name as well, will the built in password reset views work with this ?? Thanks for your help @crimsonpython24

Comment: please reply man I have a deadline for the project and I want to start creating the new user model, I do not want mess up the database and the whole code with a malfunctioning model.

Comment: I was away for a pickup game so I wasn't in front of my screen. For your question, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388858/12467282) on how to override the views. Since you already modified the fields, you can't expect the default view to work anymore.